# Saving files to App Data folder

Tags: windows, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, appdata, virtualstore

I have written a Visual Basic.Net application in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate. When this application is installed to the `Program Files` folder, when files are saved, they are located in this location:

```
C:\Users\[Username]\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files\[Company Name]\\[Application Name]
```

How can I specify to save the files in the following directory:

```
C:\Users\[Username]\AppData\[Company Name]\\[Application Name]
```

folder (basically, not the VirtualStore folder)?

Do I need to register this application within Windows to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

First, what instalation software are you using?

Second, if you're going to save your app files in the AppData directory, then you should really choose to save your app in either the, Roaming, Local, or LowLocal directory. It isn't "proper" to start making new directories where other directories are available to use, especially since the Roaming, Local, and LowLocal directories were more-or-less made to hold application's data (which is why the parent directory is call "AppData").

Comment: I am using Inno Setup. Also, I am installing my app in the Program Files directory. From there, the files are automatically saved into the AppData/VirtualStore folder when saved to disk.

Comment: Right, well i've never had any expireance with Inno Setup, i only know [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/), how can you install your app in one directory then save your files in another directory? Which files are you saving, and where?

Comment: The files I am saving are just text files. When trying to save these files to the Application.Startup folder (Located in the ProgramFiles folder), they get saved into the VirtualStore. Basically, how can I specify these files to be saved in the AppData folder that is not the VirtualStore?

Comment: Oh, right i understand. [This](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_filessection.htm) might help you.